# Unable to download pdf files from a website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi I have following code which i want to download the pdf from a website "https://www.journal-officiel.gouv.fr/balo/recherche/resultats?parutionDateStart=2021-05-17&parutionDateEnd=2021-05-17&_token=0oP3_cJ2xZ10SbEEGoNdP6vUpAIv5nBkrTZptI0Nzd8"

Here is the script that i am using to download the files but none of pdf are getting downloaded .

Though it is not giving any error it is creating a blank folder every time

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\Users\\u6080267\\Documents\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.journal-officiel.gouv.fr/balo/recherche/")
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'token')]")
link.click()

url1 = driver.current_url
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import urllib
from datetime import datetime
import requests
HEADERS = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36'}
def get_urls(url):
    
    url = url1    
    #url = https://www.journal-officiel.gouv.fr/balo/recherche/resultats?parutionDateStart=2021-05-03&parutionDateEnd=2021-05-03&_token=48BMi0HUW0CZJVdbccoO_wX9IzRJfglO8Uq-K0lfMNg
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, None, HEADERS)
    opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
    content = opener.open(req).read()  
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
    soup.prettify()      
    urls = {}
    for anchor in soup.findAll('a', href=True): #Going inside links        
        if "/balo/document" in anchor.get('href'):            
            name = anchor.get('href')[(anchor.get('href').rindex("=")+1):]
            url = "https://www.journal-officiel.gouv.fr/" + anchor.get('href')

            if name not in urls:
                urls[name]=url

    return urls
def download(urls, path):
    os.chdir(path)
    for name, url in urls.items():
        try:
            res = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)            
            # programmatic access requires a form to be submitted. On agreeing the consent, the pdfurl can be used
            soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "html.parser")
            soup.prettify()
            for pdfurl in soup.findAll(attrs={"name": "pdfURL"}):
                downloadurl = "https://www.journal-officiel.gouv.fr/" + pdfurl.get('value')
                res = requests.get(downloadurl)
                open(name + ".pdf", 'wb').write(res.content)
                print ("Downloaded", name + ".pdf")
            
        except Exception as e:
            print ("Failed to download", name, ", because of", e)   

def main():
    pathToStoreFiles = os.getcwd() + "\\" + datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    os.makedirs(pathToStoreFiles)
    urls = get_urls('')
    download(urls, pathToStoreFiles)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, you're not getting the right `pdf` download links. Also, you're making the scraping a lot more complicated than it has to be, namely, there's no need for the heavy guns of `selenium`.

The `token` *and* the query url are easily reachable with `bs4`.

You can then use it to get the `results` `HTML` and parse it for `pdf links`.

Here's how to download the first `50` files.

```python
import time

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

main_url = "https://www.journal-officiel.gouv.fr"
search_path = "/balo/recherche/"


def wait_a_bit(wait_for: float = 1.5):
    time.sleep(wait_for)


with requests.Session() as connection:
    connection.headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36"

    search_url = (
        BeautifulSoup(connection.get(f"{main_url}{search_path}").text, "lxml")
        .find_all("a", class_="aide-link")[-1]["href"]
    )

    pdf_links = (
        f'{main_url}{link.find("a")["href"]}' for link in
        BeautifulSoup(
            connection.get(f"{main_url}{search_url}&limit=50").text, "lxml"
        )
        .select(".download-link")
    )

    for pdf_link in pdf_links:
        print(f"Fetching {pdf_link}")
        pdf_file = connection.get(pdf_link).content
        with open(f'{pdf_link.rsplit("/")[-1]}.pdf', "wb") as output:
            output.write(pdf_file)
        wait_a_bit()
```

Output:

```
Fetching https://www.journal-officiel.gouv.fr/balo/document/202105172101761-59
Fetching https://www.journal-officiel.gouv.fr/balo/document/202105172101784-59
Fetching https://www.journal-officiel.gouv.fr/balo/document/202105172101798-59
Fetching https://www.journal-officiel.gouv.fr/balo/document/202105172101801-59
Fetching https://www.journal-officiel.gouv.fr/balo/document/202105172101810-59

and more ...
```

All files are saved in the script's current directory as:

```
202105172101675-59.pdf
202105172101686-59.pdf
202105172101687-59.pdf
202105172101688-59.pdf
202105172101697-59.pdf
...
```

Comment: Clean, concise, pro-efficiency and server-friendly.